# Insert value into database input or drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that a user can insert his/her level of education either by picking a value from a drop down menu or just typing some text. My code is simple:

```
<label for="education">Education: <input type="text" name="education"/> </label> 
<select name="education">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value = "Primary education" name="Primary education">Primary education</option>
   <option value = "Secondary education" name="Secondary education">Secondary education</option>
   <option value = "Bachelor" name="Bachelor">Bachelor</option>
   <option value = "Master" name="Master">Master </option>
   <option value = "Doctoral" name="Doctoral">Doctoral </option>
</select>
```

So i want to insert that value in a column called education in database. Using code above the value is inserted only when someone is picking a value from menu. Input text is not stored in database.

Comment: Where is your js and backend code? Provide your js and rest of the html

Comment: You have same name in input type and select box so in request it will always take the last one, like in this last one is selectbox which give null value or change the name of input type and select box ...

Comment: Why you using text box and select box both with same name "education" , you can show select box ONLY, in that have an option other , on selecting that only text box will be displayed

Comment: This means js or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your textbox part;

Change

```
<label for="education">Hobby: <input type="text" name="education"/> </label>
```

to

```
<label for="education">Hobby: <input type="text" name="education_text"/> </label>
```

Duplicate name causes  your problem(select and textbox name are same). I have given `education_text` as an example, update it according to your needs. Do not forget to handle it backend with updated name.

On your backend;

```
$education = "";
if(!empty($_REQUEST["education_text"])) {
   $education = $_REQUEST["education_text"];
} else if(!empty($_REQUEST["education"])) {
   $education = $_REQUEST["education"];
} else {
   die("Invalid education");
}
```

And use it in your query. You can change `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST` or `$_GET` according to your needs

Comment: But this is not related to your question

Comment: Change the name of Selectbox to education_text, then check in your code if(!empty($_REQUEST['education'])){ $education = $_REQUEST['education'];}else { $education = $_REQUEST['education_text']}   echo $education; //here save this in db

Comment: @user3169832 I have updated answer for your needs and thanks Zeeshan for your extra warning